# SQL (Oracle) : How to improve logic model and correct identifer errors?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the logic model of a video store. The client borrows the copy from the store.

[logic model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q03fR.png)  **(please see the logic model)**

After creating the logic model, the generate sequences had 5 errors.

Some of them are:

> remove the primary key

--> I cannot understand why should remove primary key.When I remove the primary key "clientno" on the client table. The software "oracle developer" doesn't let me remove the primary key.

> invalid identifer

--> Googled the info on the internet but could not understand.

The problem is on the logic model. The model want to check the average video that a client borrowed. What is the popular movie at the moment?

These are errors:

```
create table client
(
    clientno             number(8) not null,
    clientname           varchar2(30),
    clientadress         varchar2(50),
    clientclassification varchar2(30)
)
```

Error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
>   00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object”

```
alter table client 
    add constraint client_pk primary key (clientno)
```

Error:

> SQL Error: ORA-02260: table can have only one primary key
>   02260. 00000 -  "table can have only one primary key"
>   *Cause:    Self-evident.
>   *Action:   Remove the extra primary key.

```
alter table copy add constraint copy_pk primary key (copycode, client_clientno, movie_movieno)
```

Error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "COPYCODE": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier”

```
alter table store add constraint store_pk primary key (storecode, storecode1)
```

Error:

> SQL Error: ORA-02260: table can have only one primary key
>   02260. 00000 -  "table can have only one primary key"
>   *Cause:    Self-evident.
>   *Action:   Remove the extra primary key.

```
alter table copy 
    add constraint copy_client_fk 
        foreign key (client_clientno) references client (clientno)
```

Error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "CLIENT_CLIENTNO": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier”

```
alter table copy 
    add constraint copy_movie_fk 
        foreign key (movie_movieno) references movie (movieno)
```

Error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "MOVIE_MOVIENO": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of reasons why you might get one of those errors. But altogether? There's really only one explanation: you are running this script in a schema where you (or somebody else) has previously run a version of this script and created tables with those names already (perhaps with different projections).

Assuming you want to replace that schema you need to write some drop table statements and run those before you run your script. Or perhaps you need a different account.

Comment: I used to drop tables and the table really created. But there are still some errors like the "removing primary key" or "invalid identifier". It needs to improve from the logic model.

Answer (score 0):

Every single error you posted is self-evident and can easily be fixed, only if you read & understand what Oracle is telling you.

### One

`create table client` ends up with

> ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Obviously, you can't create two objects with the same name. There's *something* that is called CLIENT (most probably a table you *forgot* to drop prior to executing the command). If you're unsure of what that might be, run

```
select * from user_objects where object_name = 'CLIENT';
```

and you'll find it. Then: either drop that object, or rename the one you're currently trying to create.

### Two

As of

> ORA-02260: table can have only one primary key
>   *Cause: Self-evident.
>   *Action: Remove the extra primary key.

there's really nothing one should say ... *self-evident*, is it not?

### Three

> ORA-00904: "COPYCODE": invalid identifier

means that you used COPYCODE column in one of your commands, while that column doesn't exist in a table affected by that command. For example, you're trying to

```
alter table client modify copycode not null;
```

If there's no such a column in a table, you'd get that error.

---

I'd suggest you to go step by step: run one command, make sure it is OK. Then write another, execute it, make sure it is OK too. Go on to the next, and so forth. Baby steps.

Comment: How to improve from the logical model? For example,remove the clientno primary key from client table. But when I go to remove the primary key in the logic model , the computer do not let me remove it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wouldn't know, I don't use that tool. Did you study the instructions (documentation) which tells you how to do that action?